# How to check for matches between two phone numbers and if matched display the result from a different column

Tags: excel, vlookup

In excel, im trying to find a way to have it search for and match phone numbers on two seperate columns on two different sheets. Then if there is a match, have it display a value in a different column.

Vlookup or match function??

Comment: yes, vlookup, xlookup, or match

Comment: I'm just struggling to get the formula to work. how would you do it in an example data set6

Comment: MATCH will tell you the row of the FIRST instance on the other sheet.  COUNTIF will count the matches of on the other sheet.